# Как сделать, чтобы классы присваивались только один раз, и больше не менялись при повторных кликах?

Tags: javascript

Есть html код, примерно такой:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Нужно сделать, что бы при клике по элементу box присваивался дополнительный класс opened, а по третьему клику присваивался класс bonus, и после этого скрипт заканчивал работу, после 3-го клика классы больше не присваиваются. Так же, элементу с классом opened не может быть присвоен класс bonus, т.е. классы присваиваются элементу только один раз.
Помогите пожалуйста реализовать!

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: вы пытались это сделать?

Comment: задача с противоречием - по клику присваивается `.opened`, а на третьем `.bonus`, но элементы с классом после первого клика не могут иметь класс, присваемый третьим кликом - теперь вопрос к вам - как не нажимая первый раз перепрыгнуть сразу на третий клик?

Comment: идея в том, что бы классы присваивались только один раз, и больше не менялись. Первый клик по элементу присваивает класс opened, и другие клики по этому элементу ничего больше не присваивают. Второй клик по новому элементу то же самое. А по третьему клику по новому элементу уже класс bonus, и скрипт завершает работу. То есть клики считаются только первые по новому элементу

Answer (score 2):

ну, если я правильно всё понял. Надо что-то типо такого:

**UPD** дополнил ответ

```js
const boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
let countClick = 0;
[...boxes].map(box => {
  box.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (countClick === 3 || this.classList.contains('opened')) return;
    this.classList.add(countClick === 2 ? 'bonus' : 'opened');
    countClick++;
  });
})
```

```css
.opened {
  background: red;
}

.bonus {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: тут присваивается  класс bonus элементу с классом opened, а такого быть не должно. Клики учитываются только по элементам, не имеющими ни класс opened, ни класс bonus

Comment: @v0ndelpark дополнил ответ

Comment: @v0ndelpark дык у вас второй клик делает вещи, а не должен

Comment: Да, тут похоже! Спасибо огромное!

Comment: @highpassion как я понял, автор хочет якобы открывать коробки, а потом каждый (в данном случае 3) определенный клик, типо в коробке был бонус. Якобы если он укажет 10 то первые 9 будут обычные клики, а 10 с бонусом

Comment: @Dmitrii Sedov именно по третьему клику по коробочке, этот код работает правильно!

Comment: @DmitriiSedov господи, голову можно сломать, выполнил тоже, только мне кажется, только осталось понять, почему у вас стартовый countclick = 1

Comment: @highpassion обновил на 0  =). Просто пытался вчитаться в задачу и написал первое что пришло в голову

Comment: @DmitriiSedov я понял, всё из-за того, что я инкремент выше прибавления класса поставил поэтому у меня условие по-другому срабатывает

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант, использовать делегирование, без лишних циклов:

```js
document.querySelector('.container').addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  let classes = ev.target.classList;
  if (this.querySelector('.bonus') || !classes.contains('box') || classes.contains('open')) return;
  classes.add(((this.querySelectorAll('.open').length < 2) ? 'open' : 'bonus'));
});
```

```css
.box { border: 1px dashed #080; }
.open { background-color: #fa0; }
.bonus { background-color: #f00;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const bonus = function(e){
   const t = e.target;
   if (t.classList.contains('box')) {
     if (this.querySelectorAll('.box.opened').length == 2){
       t.className = 'box bonus';
       this.removeEventListener('click',bonus);
     } else t.className = 'box opened';
   }
}
document.querySelector('.container').addEventListener('click',bonus)
```

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}
.opened {
  background: green;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.bonus {
  background: purple;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let items = document.querySelectorAll('.container .box'),
i = 0;
items.forEach((item) => {

   item.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        i++;
        if (i < 3) event.target.classList.add('opened');
        else if (i == 3 && !(event.target.classList.contains('opened'))) {
          event.target.classList.add('bonus');
        }
   });
});
```

```css
.box {
  background: red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 42px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.opened {
  background: green;
}

.bonus {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="box">1</div>
<div class="box">2</div>
<div class="box">3</div>
<div class="box">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: в коде класс bonus присваивается классу opened, а так не должно быть...

Comment: @v0ndelpark сформулируйте задачу нормально

Comment: @v0ndelpark вы хотите убрать класс opened по третьему клику и добавить `.bonus`? обновил код, если так

Comment: нет, присвоенные классы так и остаются, они не убираются. Смысл в том, что класс bonus может быть присвоен только элементу без классов, по которому не было кликов. То есть клики учитываются только первые по новому элементу

Comment: если у элементу присваивается класс opened, То всё, никакие дальнейшие клики по нему не учитываются

Comment: @v0ndelpark обновил